# Does perfect knowledge help you prevent a subword in a word?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Let there be three words $S_1, S_2,$ and $S_3$ using letters $A$ and $B$ such that neither $S_1$ nor $S_2$ has $S_3$ as a substring. For given $S_3,$ if there is a function that takes $S_1$ and $S_2$ as inputs and outputs an $S_4$ such that $S_1 S_4 S_2$ doesn't contain $S_3,$ is this guaranteed to be achievable by a constant function?

Comment: I don't understand what the inputs for this hypothetical function are. You should explain which string(s) are inputs to the given function and which ones it doesn't get to see. Then explain the same thing for the new function you're wishing to find.

Comment: Can you understand it now?

Comment: Yep, thanks! Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this is possible.**

### Construction

Let $f(S_3, S_1, S_2)$ denote the function that we assume exists. Choose some fixed $S_3$ and let $N = |S_3|$. Denote the letters in $S_3$ by $p_k$, $1 \le k \le N$. Define the "opposite" function $o$ by $o(A) = B$ and $o(B) = A$.

Let $T_1$ be the string consisting of $N$ copies of $o(p_N)$. Let $T_2$ be the string consisting of $N$ copies of $o(p_1)$. Let $C = f(S_3, T_1, T_2)$. Then we can satisfy your requirements by choosing $S_4 = T_1 C T_2$.

### Proof

Fix some $S_1$ and $S_2$ that don't have $S_3$ as a substring. We can use cases to check that $S_1 S_4 S_2$ also doesn't have $S_3$ as a substring.

1. Fully inside $S_1$: We can't find a copy of $S_3$ here by assumption on $S_1$.
2. Crossing the border from $S_1$ into $S_4$: Any substring of length $N$ that crosses the border will end inside $T_1$, so the last letter will be $o(p_N)$, so this substring can't be a copy of $S_3$.
3. Fully inside $S_4$: It's impossible to find a copy of $S_3$ here because of the way we chose $C = f(S_3, T_1, T_2)$.
4. Crossing the border from $S_4$ into $S_2$: Analogous to case (2) above. Any substring of length $N$ that crosses the border will start inside $T_2$, so the first letter will be $o(p_1)$, so this substring can't be a copy of $S_3$.
5. Fully inside $S_2$: We can't find a copy of $S_3$ here by assumption on $S_2$.